# Passing $(this) to jQuery .hover() functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, this, scope

I wrote a simple tooltip functionality, to be seen **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/v39w12u5/)**.

The thing is, in both handler functions set in `.hover()` I need access to `$(this)` and other 2 variables based on it. In order do achieve that, I declare the same 3 variables in both handlers:

```
$('a').hover(
    function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var link_offset = $this.offset();
        var link_tooltip = $this.data('tooltip');
        // Rest of the code
    },
    function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var link_offset = $this.offset();
        var link_tooltip = $this.data('tooltip');
        // Rest of the code
    }
);
```

DRY principle should be respected, so my question is: Is there other and smarter/less dirty way of passing the same variables set to both functions within `.hover()`?

Obvioulsy, the variables can't be global (and globals are evil anyway).

Any ideas how to achieve this with jQuery or pure JS?

Comment: If you really must, you can assign the `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()` event handlers directly and route the calls via a custom function that sets these values.  But is it really needed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call one named function inside the anonymous callbacks:

```
$('a').hover(function() {
        hoverFunc($(this), true)
    }, function() {
        hoverFunc($(this), false)
    });

function hoverFunc($this, is_hovered) {
    var link_offset = $this.offset();
    var link_tooltip = $this.data('tooltip');
    if (is_hovered) {
        console.log('ok')
        // do something
    } else {
        console.log('out')
        // do something else 
    };
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/8njk2m32/

Comment: Updated answer and added a fiddle